# Magento 2 Configurable product catalog price based on filtered simple product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, layered-navigation

I have a configurable product containing simple products with different prices. For example a bucket of paint.

This configurable product contains the following simple products:

1.

```
Name = Paint White
Volume = 1L
Price = 10
```

2. 

```
Name = Paint White
Volume = 5L
Price = 50
```

Now when I filter in the layered navigation on the category page on volume 5L, the configurable product is displayed with the price of the simple product of 1L, so 10 euros. It always takes the lowest price, while I filtered on 5L and therefore have to indicate 50 euros as price.

Does anyone know how I get the price based on the filters that are active?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For that, you would have to enable the "volume" attribute as a text swatch. Then allow it to show in the product list.

The text swatch under the product tile would be automatically selected when the volume filter was applied. This would change the image & price.